# How can I hide Sheets based on the current month

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook that has a sheet in it for every month of the year and Master Item list named "Items".  I have all names as the abbreviation of the month name i.e Jan, Feb, Mar. . .Dec.  What I want to do is have all the sheets be hidden that are not for the current month i.e only see the March and Items sheet during the month of March. This is what I have for a code but I can not get it to work.  What am I missing?

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_Open()


    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim today As Varient
    
    today = Format(Date, "mmm")
    
    For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        
        If sht.Name = today Or "Items" Then
            sht.Visible = True
        Else
            sht.Visible = False
        End If
    
    Next sht

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you stepped through it to see what today comes out as? Could be that the output is based on locale and will not match your expectations. Might be easier to get the month out as a number and then get the name using a case statement or set up an array where the month names are represented by the position in the array that would be equal to the month number.

Comment: I have not done that.  I will do that and go from there.

Comment: For one I spelled Variant wrong but now I am getting a type mismatch error on `today = Format(Date, "mmm")`

Comment: That line should be fine but this:  `If sht.Name = today Or "Items" Then` should be `If sht.Name = today Or sht.Name = "Items" Then`

Comment: That did it.  I forget that I have to computer don't think the way we do.  Thank you for that.  I probably would have spent a good few days trying to come up with that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim thisMonth As Variant
    
    thisMonth = Format(Date, "mmm")
    
    For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets 
        sht.Visible = sht.Name = thisMonth Or sht.Name = "Items"
    Next sht

End Sub
```

Comment: I was just missing the `sht.Name` after the Or.  I added that to my above code and it works perfectly.